# jQuery calling on() on dynamically generated it after calling click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to develop some code to allow the user show/hide a block level element by clicking a button.

The HTML structure is like below

```
<div class="chat_container"><a class="crm" href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Chat?</a><button id="close_chat">&lt;</button></div>
```

I have written a `click()` function for `#close_chat` which amongst other things changes the ID of the button to `#open_chat`. I then use the `on()` method on `#open_chat` to modify some classes and ids on various elements. In isolation both these methods work, however when combined they don't work. I have noticed that when I click `#close_chat` even though the ID changes to #open_chat the original event is still attached to the button. After doing some search I suspected the issue might have been related to events bubbling up, but now I am not so sure, still I added `event.stopPopagation()` to my click function and I can see it appears to be called correctly. I have also tried using the `one()` method, this appeared to get closer to the behavior I was expecting at the DOM level but still didn't working

My expected behavior is the `click()` function is called when the user clicks `#close_chat`, the event is then unbound allowing the `.on()` event to be called on `#open_chat`. Id than of course have to reset the original functionality. My code looks like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

                var close = "<button id='close_chat'><</div>";

                var container = $("<div />");
                container.addClass("chat_container");

                var crmChat = $("<a />");
                crmChat.addClass("crm");
                crmChat.attr("href", "https://google.com");
                crmChat.attr("target", "_blank");
                crmChat.text("Chat?");
                console.log(crmChat);
                console.log(container);




                $(container).insertAfter("#heading");
                $(container).prepend(crmChat);
                $(close).insertAfter(crmChat);

          


                $("#close_chat").click(function (event) {
                    $("#close_chat").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "open_chat");
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    alert(event.isPropagationStopped());
                   //return false;
                });

                $(".chat_container").on("#open_chat", "button", function () {
                    //$(".crm_chat_container").addClass("animate-open").removeClass("animate-close");
                    $("#open_chat").html(">").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "reopen");
                    //event.stopPropagation();
                });


            });
```

any help is greatly appreciated
Sam

edit, I have now updated my code to look like so

```
    //onclick function for our close button
    $("#close_chat").click(function (event) {
        attachClosedChatListner();
    });

    function attachOpendChatListener() {
        $(".chat_container").on("click","#open_chat", function () {
         $("#open_chat").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "close_chat");
         $("#close_chat").html("<")
         $(".crm_chat_container").removeClass("animate-close").addClass("animate-open");
            });
           
      
        //attachClosedChatListner();
    }

    function attachClosedChatListner() {
        $("#close_chat").off('click');
        $("#close_chat").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "open_chat");
        $("#open_chat").html(">")
        $(".chat_container").removeClass("animate-open").addClass("animate-close");

        //attachOpendChatListener();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about re-attaching the event?

```
$("#close_chat").click(function (event) {
    $("#close_chat").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "open_chat");
    attachOpenChatListener();
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert(event.isPropagationStopped());
    //return false;
});

function attachOpenChatListener() {
    $("#close_chat").off('click');
    $(".chat_container").on("#open_chat", "button", function () {
        //$(".crm_chat_container").addClass("animate-open").removeClass("animate-close");
        $("#open_chat").html(">").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "reopen");
        //event.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

Comment: hi Shaedrich,

thanks for your help, unfortunately still no luck. I can see when I load the page the click event its attached to "#close_chat" and nothing is attached to ".chat_container" which is good. Clicking the button changes the div ID and alerts the propagation status. It also attaches the attachOpenChatListener function to ".chat_container", however after that it doesn't function as expected. The original click event is still bound to the button even though the ID has been updated and when I press it, it still appears to call the click function

Comment: Ah, maybe the `off()` has to be done prior to the `removeAttr()` - can you try this?

Comment: Hi Shaedrich, that's helped things but I am still stuck. I think the problem is with my use of .on(). In my original code I've used ` $(".chat_container").on("#open_chat", "button", function ()` but after looking again at the Wc3 schools reference for .on() this doesn't look right to me, I feel like it should be ` $(".crm_chat_container").on("click","#open_chat", function ()`?

Anyway, now what's happening is my first .click() event on `#close_chat`, after that things go bad, I appear to be having trouble getting a .click() event to work on `#open_chat`

Comment: i've udpated my original question with my updated code

Comment: You're right, the method signature is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work this out, the click function was causing the problem

```
//onclick function for our close button
$("#close_chat").click(function (event) {
attachClosedChatListner();
});
```

I've replaced it with .on and it works now

```
$(".crm_chat_container").on("click", "#close_chat", function (event) {
$("#close_chat").off('click');
$("#close_chat").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "open_chat");
$("#open_chat").html(">");
$(".crm_chat_container").removeClass("primo-animate-open").addClass("animate-   close");
attachCloseChatListener();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

function attachCloseChatListener() {

    $(".crm_chat_container").on("click", "#open_chat", function (event) {
        $("#open_chat").off('click');
        $(".crm_chat_container").removeClass("primo-animate-close").addClass("primo-animate-open");
        $("#open_chat").removeAttr("id").attr("id", "close_chat");
        $("#close_chat").html("<");
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
}
```

on thing is my click events appears to be firing multiple times, that is after clicking my buttons a few times I see several click events in dev tools.

Anyway, thanks for putting me on the right path

Comment: scratch that, I discover .toggleClass and used CSS properly, so the above is now distilled down to

    `$(".crm_chat_container").on("click", "#show_hide", function (event) {
        $("#show_hide").toggleClass("open_chat");
        $(".crm_chat_container").toggleClass("primo-animate-close");      
    });`